Non-genericity of lower-dimensional functions that can map in the set of rank-deficient matrices
Supose I have a continuously differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, i.e. from the set of $k-$dimensional vectors into the set of $n\times m$ matrices. Suppose that $k<nm$.
Consider the set $M\subset\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ of rank-deficient $n\times m$ matrices. Then, $M$ has Lebesgue measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.
Consider any $V\subset\mathbb{R}^k$, then $V$ and $f(V)$ have measure Lebesgue zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.
I'm looking for something that says that there are (generically) no $v\in V$ such $f(v)\in M$. My feeling is that the "generic" part must come from the set of functions.
I'm happy to parametrise is that helps, e.g. $f(;\theta)$ strictly increasing in $\theta$ with something that says that the set of $\theta$ such that there exists $v:f(v;\theta)\in M$ has Lebesgue measure zero.
The intuition is that there is generically not enough degree of freedom in $v$ to map in the set of rank-deficient matrices...
Anyone has an idea on how to proceed? It seems like I'm missing a step somewhere...
[EDIT, following a comment by Kakashi.]
Suppose that $f$ is the derivative of some function (say $g$) and let $k=n>m$. In that case, Sard's theorem says that the set of $\{v:f(v)\in M\}$ is non-generic, which is not exactly what I had in mind...
In that context, I want conditions on $f$ such that $g$ has generically no critical value. Does that make sense?

$0 \in M$, so what if $f = 0$? These matters are settled by Sard's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem

Indeed, but $f=0$ is non-generic. I'm not sure Sard's theorem applies, if I understand, but It helped me clarify the question... I've added an edit, thanks!
